# JVM SIGSEGV crash on HLT instruction?

Tags: java, segmentation-fault, crash, jvm

There seems to be a bug in OpenJDK 11.0.19 which sometimes leads to a crash in java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime().

**Final Update**: thanks to @apangin, I found out that Linux sends a SIGSEGV instead of SIGILL (which I was expecting). See last line of function http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.9/source/arch/x86/kernel/traps.c#L487

**Update**: after going back to OpenJDK 11.0.18 the issue disappeared. Anyway, I would like to understand how a HLT instruction can lead to a segmentation fault.

Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.7 (Ootpa) 4.18.0-425.19.2.el8_7.x86_64

```
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-11.0.19.0.7-1.el8_7) (11.0.19+7) (build 11.0.19+7-LTS)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-11.0.19.0.7-1.el8_7) (11.0.19+7-LTS, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# J 7581 c2 java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime()V java.base@11.0.19 (970 bytes) @ 0x00007ff72826feeb [0x00007ff72826f440+0x0000000000000aab]
```

```
Stack: [0x00007ff73ec47000,0x00007ff73ed48000],  sp=0x00007ff73ed44ad0,  free space=1014k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, A=aot compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
J 7581 c2 java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime()V java.base@11.0.19 (970 bytes) @ 0x00007ff72826feeb [0x00007ff72826f440+0x0000000000000aab]
```

```
siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 128 (SI_KERNEL), si_addr: 0x0000000000000000
```

```
Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x00000000e5b5f858, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x00007ff73ed44ad0, RBP=0x0000000000000000, RSI=0x00007ff73ed441d1, RDI=0x00007ff738023820
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x00007ff73ed44150, R10=0x00000000000007cf, R11=0x0000000000000000
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x0000000000001896, R14=0x00007ff6cda239e0, R15=0x00007ff738028800
RIP=0x00007ff72826feeb, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0x002b000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000000
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000d
```

```
Instructions: (pc=0x00007ff72826feeb)
...
0x00007ff72826febb:   08 4c 8b 6c 24 18 4c 8b c0 e9 a1 f7 ff ff be 7e
0x00007ff72826fecb:   ff ff ff 48 8b 6c 24 08 e8 28 1f 1a f8 48 bf 98
0x00007ff72826fedb:   4b bd 3d f7 7f 00 00 48 83 e4 f0 e8 25 e0 48 15
0x00007ff72826feeb:   f4 be f4 ff ff ff 48 89 1c 24 48 89 44 24 f8 8b
0x00007ff72826fefb:   44 24 10 89 44 24 08 48 8b 44 24 f8 4c 89 6c 24
0x00007ff72826ff0b:   10 66 66 90 e8 ec 1e 1a f8 be e4 ff ff ff 48 8b
0x00007ff72826ff1b:   6c 24 08 44 89 54 24 04 e8 d8 1e 1a f8 be e4 ff
0x00007ff72826ff2b:   ff ff 49 8b eb 89 5c 24 04 66 66 90 e8 c4 1e 1a
...
```

PC/RIP points to an address which contains a HLT instruction (0xF4):

```
e8 28 1f 1a f8          call   0xfffffffff81a1f45
48 bf 98 4b bd 3d f7    movabs rdi,0x7ff73dbd4b98
7f 00 00
48 83 e4 f0             and    rsp,0xfffffffffffffff0
e8 25 e0 48 15          call   0x1548e055
f4                      hlt
be f4 ff ff ff          mov    esi,0xfffffff4
48 89 1c 24             mov    QWORD PTR [rsp],rbx
48 89 44 24 f8          mov    QWORD PTR [rsp-0x8],rax
```

How can a HLT instruction trigger a segmentation violation?

I spent the last few hours searching for something similar but could not find anything.

Comment: @andrewJames: sadly, the crash only happens when the whole application is running. When I call the relevant methods in an endless loop via a separate test application, the crash never happens.

Comment: @andrewJames: we went back to OpenJDK 11.0.18 and everything works as expected. Anyway, it would be great to understand how a HLT can trigger a segmentation fault.

Comment: I see the same issue here on Rocky Linux 8 (which is a RHEL 8 clone): Crash with java-11-openjdk-headless-11.0.19.0.7-1.el8_7.x86_64, works with java-11-openjdk-headless-11.0.18.0.10-2.el8_7.x86_64 (the package version directly before the update). The issue must have been introduced with this [git commit](https://git.centos.org/rpms/java-11-openjdk/c/1f3d944bf7293313162fbf89e7d256b91aa106a6?branch=c8).

Comment: OpenJDK issue: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8307978

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HLT` is a privileged instruction. When executed in user mode, it triggers general protection fault. In Linux, this results in `SIGSEGV` being sent to the offending process.

HotSpot JVM emits `HLT` instruction in the dynamically generated code only in situations never supposed to happen. So there is apparently a JVM bug. Rerun the JVM with `-XX:+ShowMessageBoxOnError` to get more information on the particular assertion failure.

Comment: thanks, that was the info I was looking for. Do you have any idea why the compiler would place a HLT at this location? I am aware that it uses HLT for padding but it does not seem like a gap between two functions.

Comment: @kingofworms It's a kind of assertion in the generated code.